Setting up Selenium Server with Java and Spring Boot
I am trying to set up a Selenium server with Spring boot 3 + java 17. Selenium version: 4.19.1
Also i am using
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

at pom file. (its a maven project)
I am instantiate the server as below without problems.
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionId;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport;

import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@Component
public class SeliniumServer implements ISeliniumServer{

    private WebDriver Webdriver;
    private WebDriverManager webDriverManager;
    private SessionId sessionId;
    private String ServerPort;


    private String ChromeVersion="";



    public SeliniumServer() {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
        createServer();

    }


    @Override//Windows
    public void createServer() {
        webDriverManager = null;
        ChromeOptions options = ChomeSetup();
        webDriverManager =WebDriverManager.chromedriver();//.setup();
        // ksks.getDockerSeleniumServerUrl()
        webDriverManager.config().setServerPort(8081);
        webDriverManager.setup();
        try {
            Webdriver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:"+8081),options);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        Webdriver=new ChromeDriver(options);

        // driverService.getClass().getSuperclass().get

          System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------No port");
        //  e.printStackTrace();
         }

        sessionId = ((RemoteWebDriver) Webdriver).getSessionId();
        System.out.println("session ID: "+sessionId.toString());
         Webdriver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        System.out.println("window handle: "+((RemoteWebDriver) Webdriver).getCurrentUrl());
        System.out.println("port : "+webDriverManager.config().getServerPort());
        System.out.println("remote adress: "+ webDriverManager.remoteAddress("http://localhost:"+8081).toString());
        setServerPort(String.valueOf(webDriverManager.config().getServerPort()));


    }


    @Override
    public void InitialiseServer(WebDriver driver) {

    }

    @Override
    public void IntialiseServer(WebDriver driver, String URL) {

    }

    @Override
    public void IntialiseServer(WebDriver driver, String URL, String port) {

    }

    @Override
    public void CloseServer(WebDriver driver) {
        Webdriver.quit();
        Webdriver.close();

    }

    public SessionId getSessionId() {
        return sessionId;
    }

    public void setSessionId(SessionId sessionId) {
        this.sessionId = sessionId;
    }

    public WebDriver getWebdriver() {
        return Webdriver;
    }

    public void setWebdriver(WebDriver webdriver) {
        Webdriver = webdriver;
    }

    public String getServerPort() {
        return ServerPort;
    }

    public void setServerPort(String serverPort) {
        ServerPort = serverPort;
    }


    private ChromeOptions ChomeSetup()
    {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("enable-automation");
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        options.addArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation");
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.addArguments("--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false");
       // options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:4444");
        return options;
    }
}


However execution of Code never enters  on bellow snippet
  try {
            Webdriver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:"+8081),options);

        } 

And also whenever i am trying to perform a GET request to localhost:8081 using CLI commands of the server (example : http://localhost:8081/session/b1b1eb82dda432d8d8d4ad64e814c9f2/url) i am getting connection refused.
Can you please assist me?

I believe remoteURL would be for grid (there'd be no need for that if running locally).  The remoteURL is a URL to send commands to, but the webdriver/browser will be running on the remote grid's node.  The webdriver already launches a server on localhost.  You don't need to set a port as it will choose an available one.  So basically you are doing too much here and probably should not be using RemoteWebDriver... just something like new ChromeDriver().
